# Utilizing already installed MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL as a back end for my application and for this I'm installing MySQL during installation. I'm able to install/configure MySQL and able to create db and necessary tables.

Now I have a scenario where if MySQL is already installed on a particular system by some other application and user is not aware of root password, then how can I create db in MySQL or how can I utilize MySQL. Thought of creating another user but that would also require root password.

Also want to know the best approach to use MySQL. Means shall I utilize root users and use that in my application or shall I create another user just for my application.

Comment: You must request DB-Admin to create a database and user for your application and by using that user you can create all your tables and procedures under that database. And yes, you should not use root user even if you are installing fresh MySQL.

Comment: Best case would be to use users with permission restricted to the tables/databases they actually need. So no, do not use root. Generally you need a user which in case of an existing installation must be provided by the admin.

Comment: @MrZapzup - There would be no admin. In almost all the cases My application would install MySQL so I would need to install MySQL and I would be admin as well.

Comment: In that case, install database, create a user, create database, set privileges to that user specific to your database and FINISH !!

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing but what in case if MySQL is already installed on the system? If user knows the root password then I can prompt a dialog asking for root pwd but if not then do we have any workaround for this. Also Since my application would be installing MySQL, user would not be aware of root password and I will be blocking other applications.